# DateTime? formatting in blazor application

Tags: blazor

```
      <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">(@context.DateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))</MudTd>
```

DateCreated is DateTime?

I am getting this error  error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: The easiest way is `DateCreated?.ToString(...)` im assuming at this point the variable has a value.

Answer (score 4):

If `DateCreated` is nullable, try:

```cs
@context.DateCreated.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Of course, you want to be sure it is not `null`. To be sure, do something like:

```cs
<MudTd DataLabel="Nr">
  @if (context.DateCreated.HasValue)
  {
    @context.DateCreated.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
  }
</MudTd>
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach when displaying any date is to remove ambiguity.  Is 07/02/2023, 7 Feb or 2 July?  I use a global format: 07-Feb-2023.  As there are several data types, you need a few extension methods.

You can use the same approach whatever format you use.

```cs
public static class DateTimeDisplayExtensions
{
    public static string AsGlobalDate(this DateTime value)
        => value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    public static string AsGlobalDate(this DateTime? value)
        => value?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? "No Date Set";

    public static string AsGlobalDate(this DateTimeOffset value)
        => value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    public static string AsGlobalDate(this DateTimeOffset? value)
        => value?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? "No Date Set";

    public static string AsGlobalDate(this DateOnly value)
        => value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    public static string AsGlobalDate(this DateOnly? value)
        => value?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? "No Date Set";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `@context.DateCreated` is a `DateTime?`,

```
@context.DateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

makes a call to the [Nullable<T>.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=net-7.0); which, as indicated by the error message, does not take any input parameters.

---

As has already been suggested indirectly in an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370491/datetime-formatting-in-blazor-application#answer-75370533) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370491/datetime-formatting-in-blazor-application#comment-132992874), you probably *want* to call the [DateTime.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0). Specific examples have already been provided in said answer and comment:

```
@context.DateCreated?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

```
@context.DateCreated.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") // When you know DateCreated != null
```

---

I would suggest that you **create a helper/extension method** that takes a `DateTime?` object as input parameter and handles the scenario where the the input is `null`. Then you do not need to worry about `null`-checking all over, and you have full control over what is displayed (or not displayed) when you have a `null` value.

As an example, such a helper method could be as simple as the following:

```
public static string ToDateString(this DateTime? dateTime)
{
    return dateTime?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ?? "Unknown date";
}
```

and be used as follows:

```
@context.DateCreated.ToDateString()
```

If you then have two `DateTime?` objects:

```
DateTime? knownDate = new DateTime(2023, 2, 7);
DateTime? unknownDate = null;
```

the output for `knownDate.ToDateString()` and `unknownDate.ToDateString()` are, respectively:

> 02/07/2023
> Unknown date

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JXSl2Q).

---

What is impractical with that approach, though, is that the helper method *is not available for `DateTime` objects*. Therefore, a potentially better approach could be to **implement separate helper/extension methods for `DateTime?` and `DateTime` objects**, and let the first one call the second one, when appropriate.

Such helper methods could e.g. look like the following:

```
public static string ToDateString(this DateTime? dateTime)
{
    if (dateTime == null)
    {
        return "Unknown date";
    }
    
    return dateTime.Value.ToDateString();
}

public static string ToDateString(this DateTime dateTime) => dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

They are used in the same way as previously stated, both for `DateTime?` and `DateTime` objects.

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q1olv1).

Answer (score 0):

You needed to convert the value DateCreated to a DateTime first to overcome the error. Then convert it to a String and use the Strings .ToString() Format overload:

```
<MudTd DataLabel="Nr">
@if (context.DateCreated.HasValue)  {
@Convert.ToDateTime(@context.DateCreated).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
}
</MudTd>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message as the OP, and the answer provided by Bart Kiers is what worked for me.

Alternatively, you can use the [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) (?.), which will allow the formatting overload for the ToString method to appear.

```
@context.DateCreated?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```